# Output title between change in alphabetical order in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

so i'm stuck on something.

I have a load of data - lets say the array is `(brad,carl,arron,dan,fred,eli).`

I sort that to:

```
(arron,brad,carl,dan,eli,fred).
```

When i output i want it to look similar to:

```
<h1>A</h1>
<p>Arron</p>
<h1>B</h1>
<p>Brad</p>
```

etc.

But what if there are multiple names starting with the same letter - How do I see a change in letter during an loop over an array to output a title from my data.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: You can use `.charAt(0)` to get the first letter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would simply be to keep track of the last letter you saw, here is a simplistic example that assumes your names are all lower case.

```js
let names = ['arron', 'brad', 'carl', 'dan', 'eli', 'fred']
let last = '';

// Assuming all names are lower case.
for (let name of names) {
  if (last != name[0]) {
    console.log(name[0].toLocaleUpperCase());
    last = name[0];
  }
  console.log(name[0].toLocaleUpperCase() + name.substr(1));
}
```